# Tensorflow is returning unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using 3D images to fit a 3D CNN. I converted those images in Numpy 3D arrays. Then into tensors. Still, when I call the `model.fit()` command, an error saying

"ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor)"

is displayed.

Note that the numpy arrays are successfully converted into tensors as when I call the type command, the type of the arrays is returned as "tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor".

I have tried tf.constant(), tf.variable(), tf.convert_to_tensor() to convert the np arrays into tensors, still the ValueError is returning at the model.fit() command. Please someone help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Without actual code, error traceback, and even sample data, it's hard to tell what's going on.  `type` doesn't convert anything.  It almost sounds like you have an object dtype array whose elements are  themselves tensors.  Generally to make a tensor from images, we need a list of arrays that are all the same shape.  `np.array(that_list)` should then produce a multidimensional numeric dtype array.  I'd suggest examining the `type`, `shape` and `dtype` of all elements of this 'array' that you pass to `fit`.

Comment: Are your numpy arrays simple precisions? Even if it is the case it is not the error indicated. Are you input/output both tensors? If so the problem is elsewhere and a reproducible code would be welcomed.